# Using template to avoid free store?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm reading "The C++ Programming Language" Third Edition by Stroustrup Page Page 332.  He says the following code specific to the template avoids use of the free store:

```
template <class T, int i> class Buffer {
  T arr[i];
  int sz;
public:
  Buffer() : sz(i) {}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int arr[10];
  Buffer<int, 10> buf;
  return 0;
}
```

How does the template avoid use of free store compared to the declaration of int arr[10]?

Thank you!

Comment: Variable-length arrays are not part of the C++ standard, so you can't even write your `f` function in standard C++. You can't avoid the free store if you want a runtime-determined size.

Comment: @molbdnilo I wonder why g++ compiled it without warnings?

Comment: @notaorb -- because g++ supports variable-length arrays as an extension. The standard requires "a diagnostic", so you're right to expect a warning, but maybe your compiler flags weren't strict enough.

Comment: @PeteBecker g++ -pedantic catches this non-standard compliant error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Simple and constrained containers such as Buffer can be important where run-time efficiency and
>   compactness are paramount (thus preventing the use of a more general string or vector). Passing a
>   size as a template argument allows Buffer’s implementer to avoid free store use.

Variable-sized arrays require the use of the free store, or commonly (falsely) referred to as *heap*.
This is because only fixed-size objects can be stored on the stack.

```cpp
void f1(int i)
{ // i is not know at compile-time, so arr will be put on the free store
  int arr[i];
}

void f2()
{ // the size of the buffers is known at compile-time
  // they can both be stored on the stack
  Buffer<int, 10> buffer;
  int buffer2[10];
}
```

The reason why the stack can't be used for variable-sized arrays is simple: CPU architectures don't necessarily have instructions for pushing a variable amount of elements onto the stack.
And even if they did, the stack is only a few megabytes in most operating systems and you could easily exceed this limit with a variable-sized array.

As molbdnilo has pointed out, variable sized arrays are not part of the C++ standard. However, compilers such as gcc support this kind of extension.
So in practice, use `std::vector` for variable-sized arrays.

Comment: "Free store" is **not** the "stack". Free store is the term used in the standard for what is commonly known as the "heap". The "stack" is for "automatic" storage. Aside from that terminology problem, good answer. +1.

Comment: This seems like the correct answer, but I updated the question to remove the non-standard C++ code for variable array.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up @PeteBecker, big mess-up on my side. I had to make a few edits so that this answer would be correct.